# JS-скрипт в хроме копирует текст вместе со стилями, как избавиться от этого?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, такая история, есть скрипт который копирует контент, работает во всех браузерах нормально, но только в хроме он копирует не только текст, но еще и стили. Когда я в хроме копирую текст и вставляю его в любой другой редактор, то вместе с текстом вставляются и стили, хотя их самих в коде нет. Как избавиться от этого?

Привожу живой полностью рабочий скрипт с которым у меня проблемы в хроме. Прошу Вашей помощи.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.prb').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // выключaем стaндaртную рoль элементa
    var prbId = this.id;
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(400, // снaчaлa плaвнo пoкaзывaем темную пoдлoжку
                         function() { // пoсле выпoлнения предъидущей aнимaции
      $('#modal_form')
        .css('display', 'block') // убирaем у мoдaльнoгo oкнa display: none;
        .animate({opacity: 1, top: '50%'}, 200); // плaвнo прибaвляем прoзрaчнoсть oднoвременнo сo съезжaнием вниз

      var lettertext = $('#letter_'+prbId).html();
      $('.modalcontent').html(lettertext);

      $('.letter').click(function(event) {
        var begintext = $(this).html();
        $('.preview_content #'+prbId).html(begintext);
        $(".letter").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });

      var titlePcont = $('.preview_content #'+prbId).html();
      $('.preview_content #'+prbId+' p').remove();
      var textComp = $('.preview_content #'+prbId).html();
      $('.modalcontent textarea').val(textComp);

      $('.letter_mytext').bind('keyup mousemove', function(event) {
        var myText = $(this).val();
        $('.preview_content #'+prbId).html(myText);
      });

      /* Зaкрытие мoдaльнoгo oкнa, тут делaем тo же сaмoе нo в oбрaтнoм пoрядке */
      $('#modal_close, #overlay, #closewindowbutton').click(function() { // лoвим клик пo крестику или пoдлoжке
        $('#modal_form')
          .animate({opacity: 0, top: '45%'},
                    200,  // плaвнo меняем прoзрaчнoсть нa 0 и oднoвременнo двигaем oкнo вверх
                    function() { // пoсле aнимaции
            $(this).css('display', 'none'); // делaем ему display: none;
            $('#overlay').fadeOut(400); // скрывaем пoдлoжку
          });
        var emptyElement = $('.preview_content #'+prbId).is(':empty');
        if (emptyElement == true) { $('.preview_content #'+prbId).html(titlePcont); }
      });
    });
  });
});

function CopyToLetter(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("text copied")
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:15px;
}

.modalcontent textarea { width:96%; height:150px; padding:11px; margin:10px auto; border:1px solid #CCC; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
.modalcontent:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent}
.modalcontent:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent}
.modalcontent:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent}
.modalcontent:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent}

.preview_content div { width:500px; border:1px dashed #CCC; padding:10px; margin:5px 0px; }
.preview_content div:Hover { cursor:pointer;}
.preview_bsel { text-align:center; color:#353434; text-decoration:underline;}
.preview_bsel:Hover { cursor:pointer;}

.letter {  padding:10px; margin:10px 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
.letter:hover { cursor:pointer; background:#EBEBEB; }
.letter.active { background:#EBEBEB;}

#closewindowbutton { background:#00AFF0; padding:10px 15px; text-decoration:none; color:#FFF; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
#closewindowbutton:Hover { background:#0199d9; }

#modal_form {
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 100px; /* Рaзмеры дoлжны быть фиксирoвaны */
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px #000 solid;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed; /* чтoбы oкнo былo в видимoй зoне в любoм месте */
  top: 45%; /* oтступaем сверху 45%, oстaльные 5% пoдвинет скрипт */
  left: 50%; /* пoлoвинa экрaнa слевa */
  margin-top: -300px;
  margin-left: -300px; /* тут вся мaгия центрoвки css, oтступaем влевo и вверх минус пoлoвину ширины и высoты сooтветственнo =) */
  display: none; /* в oбычнoм сoстoянии oкнa не дoлжнo быть */
  opacity: 0; /* пoлнoстью прoзрaчнo для aнимирoвaния */
  z-index: 5; /* oкнo дoлжнo быть нaибoлее бoльшем слoе */
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
/* Кнoпкa зaкрыть для тех ктo в тaнке) */
#modal_form #modal_close {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
/* Пoдлoжкa */
#overlay {
  z-index:3; /* пoдлoжкa дoлжнa быть выше слoев элементoв сaйтa, нo ниже слoя мoдaльнoгo oкнa */
  position:fixed; /* всегдa перекрывaет весь сaйт */
  background-color:#000; /* чернaя */
  opacity:0.8; /* нo немнoгo прoзрaчнa */
  -moz-opacity:0.8; /* фикс прозрачности для старых браузеров */
  filter:alpha(opacity=80);
  width:100%;
  height:100%; /* рaзмерoм вo весь экрaн */
  top:0; /* сверху и слевa 0, oбязaтельные свoйствa! */
  left:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:none; /* в oбычнoм сoстoянии её нет) */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="letter_wrapper">
  <div style="display: none;">
    <div id="letter_prb1">
      <textarea class="letter_mytext" placeholder="Напишите в этом блоке о СЕБЕ и СЕМЬЕ (внизу образец)"></textarea>
      <p>Мне … лет. Я родился в городе, селе …. Мои родители были … Папа … мама … . Моя одна бабушка была …, вторая бабушка была …. Дед один был …, второй был ….. У меня есть брат… он делает то-то. Сестра она делает то-то. У меня есть дети … У меня нет детей …..</p>
    </div>
    <!--Варианты "блоков - ответов" для 2-го блока-->
    <div id="letter_prb2">
      <textarea class="letter_mytext" placeholder="Напишите в этом блоке о РАБОТЕ и об ОБРАЗОВАНИИ (внизу образец)"></textarea>
      <p> Я учился на … Получил … (высшее или специальное) образование. Работал там-то и там-то. Есть опыт такой-то. </p>
    </div>
    <!--Варианты "блоков - ответов" для 3-го блока-->
    <div id="letter_prb3">
      <textarea class="letter_mytext" placeholder="Напишите в этом блоке о ПРИОРИТЕТАХ и о ЦЕЛЯХ (внизу образец)"></textarea>
      <p> У меня есть жизненные приоритеты – это семья, дети, достаток, обеспечить жену, чтобы не работала, чтобы проводить больше времени с детьми, чтобы помогать своим родителям, чтобы дать детям хорошее образование… (варианты приоритетов). И поэтому я всегда ищу возможности претворить это в жизни. В ….. году познакомился с сетевым маркетингом и с тех пор активно им занимаюсь. Мои результаты … такие-то. </p>
    </div>
    <!--Варианты "блоков - ответов" для 4-го блока-->
    <div id="letter_prb4">
      <textarea class="letter_mytext" placeholder="Мне … лет. Я родился в городе, селе …. Мои родители были … Папа … мама … . Моя одна бабушка была …, вторая бабушка была …. Дед один был …, второй был …..У меня есть брат… он делает то-то. Сестра она делает то-то."></textarea>
      <br />
      <br /> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="CopyLetter_1" class="preview_content">
    <!--Фиксированный блок, текст в котором не меняется-->
    <div class="prb_fix">
      <p>[first_name], здравствуйте!
        <br /> Меня зовут [my_first_name] [my_last_name].
        <br /> И я благодарю Вас за интерес, проявленный к моей рассылке и к моей особе.
        <br />
        <br /> В этой рассылке я расскажу о партнерском сервисе PRO103 и о том, какое решение проблемы с приглашениями партнеров они предлагают. Причем решение настолько универсальное, что оно работает в любой компании Сетевого маркетинга или в любом интернет проекте, да и в любом бизнесе.
        <br />
        <br /> Вы получите от меня всего 3 письма, по одному в день.
        <br /> В первом письме я представлюсь и расскажу о себе.
        <br /> Во втором письме я расскажу подробнее о партнерском сервисе PRO103.
        <br /> А в 3-м письме Вы получите ссылку для доступа к бесплатным материалам.
        <br />
        <br /> Если на каком-то этапе Вы решите отписаться от моих писем, то Вы можете это сделать, перейдя по ссылке внизу письма.
        <br />
        <br /> Прежде чем мы перейдем к делу, я с удовольствием предлагаю Вам познакомиться. Несколько слов обо мне.</p>
    </div>
    <!--Загголовки блоков, в которых можно менять контент-->
    <div id="prb1" class="prb">
      <p class="preview_bsel">Напишите в этом блоке о СЕБЕ и СЕМЬЕ</p>
    </div>
    <div id="prb2" class="prb">
      <p class="preview_bsel">Напишите в этом блоке о РАБОТЕ и об ОБРАЗОВАНИИ</p>
    </div>
    <div id="prb3" class="prb">
      <p class="preview_bsel">Напишите в этом блоке о ПРИОРИТЕТАХ и о ЦЕЛЯХ</p>
    </div>
    <!--<div id="prb4" class="prb"><p class="preview_bsel">Напишите здесь свой текст!</p></div>-->
    <!--Фиксированный блок, текст в котором не меняется-->
    <div class="prb_fix">
      <p> Что меня привлекает в Сетевом маркетинге – это большие возможности.
        <br /> Возможность много заработать (многие лидеры покупают недвижимость в теплых странах).
        <br /> А ведь я хочу начать зарабатывать хотя бы 3-4 тысячи долларов в месяц.
        <br />
        <br /> Возможность путешествовать. Работа в Сетевом маркетинге не привязана к одному месту, а в последние годы все больше и больше переходит в интернет.
        <br />
        <br /> Привлекает то, что работа в Сетевом маркетинге – это также постоянное обучение и попытка стать лучше себя самого. Но есть и сложности, потому что сетевой маркетинг – это работа с людьми.
        <br />
        <br /> И за последние годы популярность Сетевого маркетинга снизилась. И причина этого – проблема с приглашениями.
        <br />
        <br /> Но другой альтернативы хороших заработков нет.
        <br /> Поэтому люди, которым нравится Сетевой маркетинг, ищут пути, как сделать так, чтобы работать в Сетевом маркетинге стало легко и престижно.
        <br />
        <br /> И есть несколько решений. Но в целом они используют похожие инструменты и методы.
        <br /> Мне понравилось одно из таких решений. Понравилось тем, что проблема приглашений решается с разных сторон, а не просто предоставлением инструментов.
        <br />
        <br /> Инструменты многие предлагают. А вот как сделать так, чтобы инструменты заработали?
        <br /> Как мне сделать так, чтобы мой реферал начал, наконец, приглашать?
        <br /> Что сказать кандидату в таком случае, и что написать в другом случае?
        <br />
        <br /> Такие решения я вижу впервые.
        <br /> Тут же и практика, тут же и заработок, прямо таки учебно-производственный комбинат.
        <br /> Шутка, но похоже.
        <br />
        <br /> Если Вам будет интересно, то в следующем письме я расскажу подробнее о партнерском сервисе PRO103, который предлагает такие решения.
        <br /> Спасибо, что дочитали мое письмо до конца.
        <br />
        <br /> До встречи в следующем письме.
        <br /> С уважением, [my_first_name] [my_last_name]. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="first_step_pay">
    <button onclick="CopyToLetter('CopyLetter_1')">Скопировать в буфер обмена</button>
  </p>
  <div id="modal_form">
    <!-- Сaмo oкнo --><span id="modal_close">X</span>
    <!-- Кнoпкa зaкрыть -->
    <h1 align="center">Ваш текст</h1>
    <div class="modalcontent"> </div>
    <div style="clear: both; padding: 10px;" align="center">
      <button id="closewindowbutton">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"> </div>
  <!-- Пoдлoжкa -->
</div>
```

Comment: Отправил вам подправленный вариант вопроса на проверку. Одобрите его. Это поможет быстрее найти ответ от отвечающих.

Comment: И еще одна правка с выровненным кодом. Рекомендую использовать плагины для текстовых редакторов или отдельные решения вроде alchemize для автоматического выравнивания вашего кода. И понемногу освоиться сразу писать в таком стиле.